# python version differences in terminal and pycharm terminal

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use OX10.11.3 and in the terminal when I type python I get:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 12:54:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

and so the matplotlib version is:

```
print matplotlib.__version__
1.5.1
```

However in pycharm terminal I see:

```
Python 2.6.9 (unknown, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
```

and so the matplotlib version is:

```
print matplotlib.__version__
1.1.1
```

I need to use some features of matplotlib that exist in newest versions but I do not know how to update it. What are these differences in Pythons I have?

Comment: Clearly you are using a different interpreter and environment in PyCharm - go to the project interpreter settings to alter this, and read up on *"virtual environments"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the project interpreter in pycharm. the pycharm docs are very thorough https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html

also consider using something like virtualenv in the future as it will help to avoid problems like this https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/